# Search for the closest entry from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables A and B that have the same fields.
What i am trying to do is to search for the closest entry in table B by comparing different fields in both tables. (Or basically search for a benchmark for A listed in table B)
What i have done so far is:

```
SELECT  A.Id , B.Id  FROM A , B
order by ABS (a.Volume - b.Volume)+ ABS(a.FCDate-b.FCDate)+ ABS(a.IssueDate-b.IssueDate)
```

The problem with this query is that it returns a cartesian product. What I'd like to have is to have only one result from table B (the top 1 for example) for every entry in table A.

Let's take an example:

```
Table A 
id        Volume        FCDate        IssueDate
1         100           2014-01-01    2012-01-01

Table B
id        Volume        FCDate        IssueDate
1         95            2012-07-15    2000-01-01
2         100           2014-02-15    2004-01-01
3         100           2014-02-15    2011-09-20
```

The result of the query must be:

```
A.Id       B.Id
1          3
```

In this case the result is immediate using the linear formula above. But with the data i have (+4000 entries), I have sometime 3 ou 4 results. In this case, I think picking the top 1 would be fine

Comment: @Strawberry I wouldn't say it's offtopic, the explanation is rather clear. But some sample data  would help, indeed...

Comment: Ok i must admit it wasn't obvious. I posted an example to try to explain even more

Comment: One unclear thing is the weight you give to each "tuple". Doing a `datetime - anotherdatetime` give you results widely overweighting the Volume : even if you change Volume (for third entry) to 30000, this will still be the first returned data. Don't you wanna use a Datediff, for example ?

Comment: I agree with you. But don't pay attention to the weight for the moment. It will be adjusted afterwards.(in fact Volume is expressed in billions so it doesn't really change the results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you need a sub query to get the smallest difference for each record on A, and then join to B where the difference is the same.

```
SELECT  A.Id AS aid, B.Id AS bid
FROM A 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  A.Id , MIN(ABS (a.Volume - b.Volume)+ ABS(a.FCDate-b.FCDate)+ ABS(a.IssueDate-b.IssueDate))  AS MinDiff
    FROM A 
    CROSS JOIN B
    GROUP BY A.Id
) sub0
ON A.Id = sub0.Id
INNER JOIN B
ON ABS (a.Volume - b.Volume)+ ABS(a.FCDate-b.FCDate)+ ABS(a.IssueDate-b.IssueDate) = sub0.MinDiff
```

I don't expect this to be quick, given the calculation required on the JOIN. It will also struggle if 2 records on B have the same difference to a single record on A

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03987/3

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this immediately.

Comment: +1. If you have 2 records on B with the same difference, you will just get both, which may be wanted (or not). But if you want only one result by A in this case, you'll have to find a way to discriminate them.

Comment: You can add GROUP BY A.Id to the final query. This will eliminate all B.id-s but one although it's hard to predict which one remains

Comment: @RuslanBes It is a bit of an abuse of GROUP BY (and against SQL standards, although MySQL would allow it through). Possibly use `SELECT A.Id, MIN(B.Id).....GROUP BY A.Id` to get the match with the lowest id.